# How to find matrix A for this question using span and null space (linear algebra)?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9drE.png)

For this question I need to find what matrix A is, but I don't know what to do it since the question only has null space and span. I thought A was [-1 -1] but I'm sure it's wrong.

Could somebody help me with that? Thank you so much!

I want to display the image here but the website it needs 10 reputations to do so. Sorry for the inconvinence :(

Comment: Write a general matrix $A$ and see this statements:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
-2 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Can you find $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: By doing the inverse of it? Like [0 0] times the inverse of [1 1]?

Comment: try doing the multiplication and equating the components

Comment: Multiplying which by which? Does this mean the inverse of [1 1] multiplying by [0 0]?

Comment: multiplying (general) matrix ($A$) by vector

Comment: What they are suggesting is to get explicit equations. Consider the first matrix equation that @Mateus wrote. You multiply $A$ with [1,-2] as a result you have $[a-2b,c-2d]=[-1,2]$, i.e. $a-2b=-1$ and $c-2d=2$. Do the same for the second matrix equation and solve for $a,b,c,d$ to get your matrix $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen $A$ as linear transformation, you have that $A(1,-2)=(-1,2)$ and $A(1,1)=0$. Note that this is enough to determine completely our transformation $A$ since ${(1,-2),(1,1)}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2

Let's compute what is $A$ explicitely, i.e. let's compute $A(x,y)$ as a formula of $x,y$. To do this, we express $(x,y)$ as a linear combination of $(1,-2)$ and $(1,1)$, i.e. we need to find $a,b$ (in terms of $x,y$) such that 
 $$(x,y)=a(1,-2)+b(1,1)$$ 
This leads to two (linear) equations
\begin{align*}
x=a+b\\
y=-2a+b
\end{align*} 
Solving this equation, you get $a=\frac{x-y}{3}$ and $b=\frac{2x+y}{3}$.

Now, we can compute $A(x,y)$ as follows:

Hence \begin{align*}A(x,y)&=A(a(1,-2)+b(1,1))\\
&=aA(1,-2)+bA(1,1)\\
&=\frac{x-y}{3}(-1,2)+\frac{2x+y}{3}(0,0)\\
&=\left(-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}y\,,\, \frac{2}{3}x-\frac{2}{3}y\right).
\end{align*}

So, as a matrix $$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{2}{3}&-\frac{2}{3}
\end{array}\right)$$
because $$A{x\choose y}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{2}{3}&-\frac{2}{3}
\end{array}\right){x\choose y}={-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}y\choose \frac{2}{3}x-\frac{2}{3}y}$$

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how to get =(−)/3  and =(2+)/3. Could u elaborate more on that?

Comment: and what do x and y mean in this case? thank you so much for your answer but i don't really get it.

Comment: $(x,y)$ Is just a generic vector. I am expressing any vector $(x,y)$ as a linear combination of $(1,-2)$ and $(1,1)$.